# @foreach not working well with model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to give ASP.NET a shot today and created a simple database with one table called navigation. When I send the data from the controller to the view however I notice that I can use @model.name for instance but it won't let me use a foreach loop on model and I cannot figure out why.

here is the code

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Models;

namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers
{
    public class navigationsController : Controller
    {
        private edulyEntities db = new edulyEntities();

        // GET: navigations
        public ActionResult ShowMenu()
        {
            return View(db.navigation.ToList().OrderBy(n => n.nav_order));
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Models.navigation>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action(Model.action, Model.controller)" class="dont-break-out">
            <i class="@Model.glyphicon_text"></i>
            <span class="smScreenHideText">@Model.name</span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

database table

```
 public partial class navigation
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int nav_order { get; set; }
    public string glyphicon_text { get; set; }
    public string controller { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're never referencing your `item` variable inside your `foreach` loop, like @MihailStancescu said below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `glyphicon_text` is a property in `WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Models.navigation` class then you should update the code inside the `foreach` like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li>
     <a href="@Url.Action(Model.action, Model.controller)" class="dont-break-out">
        <i class="@item.glyphicon_text"></i>
        <span class="smScreenHideText">@item.name</span>
     </a>
   </li>
}
```

Notice that I've replaced `@Model` with `@item` because your are now in the scope of the `foreach` and you've declared `item` to be the object inside the collection passed from the controller.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!